# Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir este JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

O seguinte erro esta sendo apresentado:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

na linha 12. Gostaria de que alguém me ajudasse a corrigir este erro.

O JS é o seguinte:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:{
            noticias: []
        },
        methods:{
            sync:function(){
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json'
                    url: 'http://yhsoftware.esy.es/read.php',
                    success:function(dados){
                        localStorage.setItem('noticias',JSON.stringify(dados));
                        vm.setNoticias();
                        alert("lista de noticias atualizada!");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("ocorreu um erro durante a conexão com o servidor!");
                    }
            }};
        },
        setNoticias:function(){
            this.noticias = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('noticias'));
            console.log(this.noticias);
        }
    },
    ready:fuction(){
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Falta vírgula depois de `dataType: 'json',`
- Falta um **n** no `ready:function(){`
- Na linha 21 isto aqui está a mais:

  ```
      }};
  ```

O aninhamento correto não dá pra saber, depende do fim do código.

Entenda que quando você passa um objeto, como este que está mandando para o `vue`, a sintaxe é basicamente essa:

```
{ "nome1":"valor", "nome2":"valor" }
```

ou no caso de listas de valores, arrays:

```
[ valor, valor, valor ]
```

e pode combinar as duas coisas:

```
{ "lista": [ 1, 2, 3 ], "objeto": { "a":1, "b":2 }, "funcao":function(){...} }
```

Note que os valores e pares são sempre separados por vírgulas. Você só vai ter `;` quando definitivamente a instrução toda acabar.

**Nota:** se você colar o código no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/pen)**, por exemplo, ele já avisa tudo isso pra você (aparece uma exclamação em vermelho, que quando clicada, mostra a linha com problema). É mais adequado do que trazer correção de erro para cá.